# Java: Get PrivateKey from Windows-MY Certificate (not exportable) to use it for SSL Auth

Tags: java, authentication, ssl, https, private-key

How can I get the PrivateKey from a Windows-MY (MSCAPI) Certificate (marked as not exportable) to use it for the HTTPS Connection to authentificate the Client.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to use Java Web Start to wrap my application.  It handles the SSL context stuff including prompting the user for the certificate.  I attempted at first to get the private key through SunMSCAPI but the private key became corrupt every time.

Java web start was my solution.  Your JAR's need to be signed to run under JWS.  Your application will be launched via a JNLP file.  Google JWS JNLP example for an example.  It's pretty easy.

Comment: How does this help you sign HTTPS requests in 2-way SSL connections? You never see the private key...